# Put a hook in a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to put a hook in state for the initialization of my variable :

```
state = { 
    geo: new usePosition()
}
```

But I got the following error :

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I really need to put this hook in my state for the initialization of my variable...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Why not to initiate it in your main App render script? Define state with empty value and then set to new usePosition() in render method (for functional component) or do it in constructor of Component

Comment: Out of curiosity, you are using hooks in class component ? Why not using them in functional component with useState hook ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use this way. What you can do is, in your `componentDidMount()`, you can try doing it:

```
state = { geo: null };
componentDidMount() {
  const geo = new usePosition();
  this.setState({ geo });
}
```

So this is available inside the `render()` function through:

```
this.state.geo
```

Also, just a suggestion. If you're using hooks, please use it on a functional component along with a `useState()` and a `useEffect()` hook.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your answer but I got the following message : ```Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app```

Comment: Yes again unfortunately :/

Comment: @Peter Can you move it to the render function something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-jang-r0rto?file=/src/Peter.js

Comment: @Bob Tried something else like this. Moving it to the render function something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-jang-r0rto?file=/src/Peter.js

Comment: I tried but I got this : `Identifier 'usePosition' has already been declared (16:6)`

Comment: I put `usePosition = () => {};` just above `class App extends Component {}`

Comment: @Peter Don't use that... Just remove that line. I have just gave that for not showing any error. You have got it defined already.

Comment: I remove that line but I still get an error : 

``` 
render() {
     if (!this.state.geo){
         const geo = new usePosition();
           this.setState({geo})
       }
       return ( ```

I got the same error : 

```Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app```

Comment: @Peter Where did you get your `usePosition` hook from?

Comment: I put the usePosition hook like this :

``` render() {
        if (!this.state.geo){
            const geo = new usePosition();
            this.setState({geo})
        }
        return ( ...) } ```

Comment: @Peter Please send me the full code? Can I see it on https://CodeSandbox.io or some Cloud IDE?

Comment: Sure, you can see the full code here : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-bush-jwiqu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Peter Checking it now.

Comment: @Peter I have made it work by using Functional Components here: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-mountain-1gtz9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Do you think you can accept this as a right code in the code sandbox?